# Returning a struct from a Haskell FFI callback

Tags: haskell

I need to be able to call this function where `native_call_cb` is implemented by a Haskell function

```
typedef godot_variant (*native_call_cb)(void *, godot_array *);
void GDAPI godot_register_native_call_type(const char *p_call_type, native_call_cb p_callback);
```

godot_variant is a struct

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t _dont_touch_that[GODOT_VARIANT_SIZE];
} godot_variant;
```

Haskell FFI doesn't support returning structs, so the best i can do is

```
godot_variant* (*native_call_cb)(void *, godot_array *)
```

using

```
foreign import ccall "wrapper" (Ptr () -> Ptr GodotArray -> IO (Ptr GodotVariant)) -> IO (FunPtr (Ptr () -> Ptr GodotArray -> IO (Ptr GodotVariant)))
```

How can I convert a `Ptr () -> Ptr GodotArray -> IO (Ptr GodotVariant)` into a C function pointer of type `native_call_cb` without defining a C wrapper for each function?

E: If I define a wrapper for each function, it's simple:

```
foreign export ccall my_func :: Ptr () -> Ptr GodotArray -> IO (Ptr GodotVariant)
foreign import ccall "&my_func_wrapper" :: FunPtr (Ptr () -> Ptr GodotArray -> IO Void) -- placeholder for struct
```

and a C wrapper

```
godot_variant my_func_wrapper(void* desc, godot_array* array) {
    return *my_func(desc, array);
}
```

That's cumbersome, though

Comment: "Haskell FFI doesn't support returning structs"  Where did you learn this?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson from [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface): Warning: GHC does not support passing structures as values yet.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, added it. Knew I was forgetting something.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CStructures https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch8.html#x15-1560008.4.2

Comment: Yes, thank you DavidKraeutmann and @YotamOhad, I had fogotten this restriction.  Most C code already passes pointers instead of values for structs which conveniently avoids this issue.  We're left with Daniel's request for clarification on what is being asked.

Comment: `How can I convert a Ptr () -> Ptr GodotArray -> IO (Ptr GodotVariant) into a C function pointer of type native_call_cb without defining a C wrapper for each function?`

Comment: @DavidKraeutmann If all your functions have the same type, why can you not reuse the wrapper? `foreign import ccall "wrapper" mkNativeCallCb :: (Ptr () -> Ptr GodotArray -> IO (Ptr GodotVariant)) -> IO (FunPtr (Ptr () -> Ptr GodotArray -> IO (Ptr GodotVariant)))`. Now, `mkNativeCallCb` is the one function you need.

Comment: Because I need to dereference the pointer to GodotVariant